# On definition of alternating multilinear form

Tags: differential-geometry

I am still trying to understand differential forms. I understand that locally a differential $p$-form is a alternating multilinear form $T_xM \times \dots \times T_xM \to \mathbb R$ where the domain is a $p$-times product of the tangent space on the manifold at point $x \in M$.

The problem is, [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_operators) an alternating form appears to be a form such that if any two arguments are linearly dependent then it is $0$.

On the other hand, on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingMultilinearForm.html) it appears to be defined such that if any two arguments are swapped then the sign changes.

But I think both of these need to be satisfied by a differential form. Are these definitions wrong?

Comment: The definitions are equivalent (over a field of characteristic not equal to $2$). This is a nice exercise.

Comment: Great, thank you for your comment!